# ssis comparing two huge amount of data tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

(SSIS) I have a target table which having 32 million records, and i just want to compare with the newly came 32 million records, in that newly came records there may be (new records and updated or modified records and also old records).i want to compare and insert new records, updated or modified records and omit old records.
see i used lookup took too much of time. so please help me to overcome comparing time to resolve my performance issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSIS. Either perform joins, or *don't* bring in 32M records. Enable change tracking on the source database and *only* bring in the rows that changed. Without change tracking, the comparison will take a long time no matter what - even with indexes, you *are* comparing 32M rows with 32M rows.

Comment: Apart from that, you don't provide any information so one can only speculate. Does the source data have a `changed` columnd or not? You could use this to read only the rows that changed after the last import. Is the primary key incremental? You could use this to load only the *keys* that were created after the last import. You could use either option to *avoid* loading 32M records.

Comment: Another option is to perform the updates in batches . This will avoid flooding tempdb and filling up the transaction log

Comment: Look into using an execute sql task with the Merge statement.

Comment: @JoeC a merge of 32M rows with 32M rows will be interesting. Never mind that MERGE isn't atomic. The problem isn't how to execute a SQL statement. It's what statement(s) should be executed and how

Comment: Might be a case for SCD1... but after all: 32 Mio records are 32 Mio records - they WILL require some time to compare etc.

Comment: @Tyron78 SCD is about *dimensions* and a small number of records. SC stand for `slowly changing`. This is about identifying and importing modified data, probably for a fact table

Comment: Yes, I know that it is for Dimensions. However, used it for other types of data as well - always depends on the requirement. Another approach would be partitioning of the tables, then switch out partitions and compare them / merge them / whatsoever before switching it back again. This is what we do for several fact tables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The thing is sources are completely a flat file, or CVS or excel etc(80+ files). so we cant do anything on the source side. we load all the data to some staging tables first, then we will do some validation then we come up will the proper records. so we are comparing those proper records with the existing records(32 millions to 32 millions).we are implementing SCD2 once the comparison got over we will load those updated records to some other  extension table.In that main table we wont keep historical records but in the extension table we keep those historical records.

Comment: @RajakrishnanKK how does the file look like? How does the data change? Is it *appended*, sorted in some way? If new data gets upended, you start loading rows starting from the last import's position. If ordered by date or another key, the same. SCD is 10000% wrong for this. It means *Slowly* Changing *Dimensions*. This isn't a dimension, it's fact data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look at all 32 million incoming records every time to see if any of them have changed, then the most performant solution is to just replace all of the existing records with the new ones whether they have changed or not.

Import all 32 million records to a staging table and then do a switch or rename to make the staging table the new permanent table.